# create a workable array from existing array in php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have trouble understanding arrays and I was wondering if someone could help me reformat an existing array in php.

**This is the existing array:**

```
Array
(
[item] => Array
(
    [0] => item listing 1
    [1] => item listing 2
)

[description] => Array
(
    [0] => item testing description
    [1] => item testing description
)

[rate] => Array
(
    [0] => 1.00
    [1] => 2.00
)

[itemid] => Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
)
```

**I want it to look like this:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [item] => item listing 1
    [description] => item testing description
    [rate] => 1.00
    [itemid] => 1
)
[1] => Array
(
    [item] => item listing 2
    [description] => item testing description
    [rate] => 2.00
    [itemid] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the length of all the sub-arrays in the first one are the same this should work.

Assume the first array above is in a variable `$inArray`; the new array is `$outArray`.

```
$outArray = array();
$iLength  = count($inArray['item']);
for($i=0; $i<$iLength; $i++) {
    $outArray[] = array(
        'item'        => $inArray['item'][$i],
        'description' => $inArray['description'][$i],
        'rate'        => $inArray['rate'][$i],
        'itemid'      => $inArray['itemid'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: whoops, that's what I get for editing directly in the web page!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so if your master array is called $master.  Then you'd do something like this:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($master as $key => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $k2 => $value) {
        $newArr[$k2][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Woops I had that there when I thought I needed to keep track of the array key, then realized I had access to it from $k2 :).  Moved it out to remove confusion.

Comment: For what it's worth I think this should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working for your specific use case(copy/paste on a blank php):

```
$master = array( 
  'itemid' => array(1, 2),
  'items' => array('item listing 1', 'item listing 2'),
  'description' => array('item testing description', 'item testing description'),
  'rate' => array(1.10, 2.10)
);

$newItems = array();
foreach($master['itemid'] as $index => $id) {
  $newItem = array(
    'itemid' => $id,
    'item' => $master['items'][$index],
    'description' => $master['description'][$index],
    'rate' => $master['rate'][$index],
  );
  $newItems[] = $newItem;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newItems);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Note that you can also test code and link to a runnable sample using the excellent site http://ideone.com/.

Comment: But the output is confusing, I prefer this: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ :) (however this does not work as "paste bin" but the output is more clear.